What is best way to change primary key of large table with minimal downtime?
Due to latch contention on large table with more than 1 billion records, I would like to reorder primary key definition from big int column to composite primary key. I know of two ways of doing this...

Drop constraint and add constraint
I think this would take way to much downtime/time when table is unusable.
Copy records into new table
with composite primary key, then take downtime, finish copying all remaining records, switch table names and create necessary index. Using Change Tracking for copying updated rows during downtime.

Disk space and RAM shouldn't be issue. Switching to minimally logged recovery model makes sense. Are there any gotchas or tips that would help me optimize this process ?
Are there any other ways to make this change with minimal downtime?
Running on SQL Server 2016. Most inserts are single rows inserts, I am seeing PAGELATCH_EX with nearly 300ms wait duration.
